# IsoSettingsManager

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-7

Just a wrapper around IsolatedStorageSettings.

The only thing i'm not sure about is isoSettings.Save(); Should i call it there? Looking like it works without it, setting [] is enough.

```
class IsoSettingsManager
{
    private static readonly IsolatedStorageSettings isoSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    /// <summary>
    /// Set a property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    /// <param name="content"></param>
    public static void SetProperty(string propertyName, object content)
    {
        isoSettings[propertyName] = content;
        isoSettings.Save();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads value from IsolatedStorageSettings. 
    /// WARNING: returns null, if property is not found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static object GetProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        if (isoSettings.Contains(propertyName) && isoSettings[propertyName] != null)
                return isoSettings[propertyName];

        return null; 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads reference from IsolatedStorageSettings. 
    /// WARNING: returns default(), if property is not found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T GetProperty<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        if (isoSettings.Contains(propertyName) && isoSettings[propertyName] != null)            
            return (T) isoSettings[propertyName];            

        return default(T);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes property, if already exists
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    public static void RemoveProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        if (isoSettings.Contains(propertyName))
            isoSettings.Remove(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use your `GetProperty` method there is no way to find out did you get a real property value or some default value.

It will be more clear if you'll use a standard TryGet pattern here:

```
public static bool TryGetProperty<T>(string propertyName, out T result)
{
    if (isoSettings.Contains(propertyName) && isoSettings[propertyName] != null)
    {
        result = (T) isoSettings[propertyName];
        return true;            
    }

    result = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The IsolatedStorageSettings supports the TryGetValue method so there is no need to create it manually.

Comment: yep, my bad. So it can be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things which could be improved. Argument validation, better error handling, duplicate code removal and potentially better API for handling missing value for a given property name. Personally, I am not a big fan of TryGet pattern.

Here's how I would write it:

```
public static class IsoSettingsManager
{
    private static readonly IsolatedStorageSettings isoSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    // All arguments of public methods must be validated.
    public static void SetProperty(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

        //I added this check only because in your original GetProperty method
        //you treat 'null' as a missing value for a given property name. 
        //In that case, it makes sense to not allow null content to be set
        //as property value.

        //You want to carefully think about whether a null content is a valid 
        //value or not for your end users and adjust the code accordingly.
        if(propertyValue == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyValue");

        isoSettings[propertyName] = propertyValue;
        isoSettings.Save();
    }

    public static object GetProperty(string propertyName, object alternateValue)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

        //We don't validate alternateValue because user may want to return 'null'
        //as an alternate.      
        return isoSettings.Contains(propertyName) ? isoSettings[propertyName] : alternateValue;
    }

    //Instead of repeating the code of non generic GetProperty method, we will
    //use it here.
    public static T GetProperty<T>(string propertyName, T alternateValue)
    {
        var propertyValue = GetProperty(propertyName, alternateValue);      

        //Let's ensure that the property value is of the right type.

        //Below logic is strict about type casting. 
        //Potentailly, CAST can also invoke conversion and if you want to adapt to 
        //that you should use the function outlined in this answer:
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399273/test-if-convert-changetype-will-work-between-two-types/1399454#1399454
        if(propertyValue.GetType() != typeof(T))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Property value for Property Name " + propertyName + " is of type " + propertyValue.GetType().Name + " and it can not be casted to type " + typeof(T).Name);

        return (T) propertyValue;
    }

    public static T GetProperty<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        return GetProperty<T>(propertyName, default(T));
    }

    public static void RemoveProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

        if (isoSettings.Contains(propertyName))
            isoSettings.Remove(propertyName);
    }
}
```