# DataService data storage

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, windows-phone-7

I have a `DataService`, which should talk to the server and store vars (for complicated calls, for example).

Last time, I ended up with this approach (for the example, I'm working with a list):

- `GetList()` - returns cached data (just a property)
- `SetList()` - sets a property
- `ReadList()` - read data from file from `IsoStorage`
- `WriteList()` - write data to file
- `PullList()` - pull data from the server
- `PushList()` - push data to the server

NB: I'm using my old `IsoStorage` approach ([IsoSettingsManager](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33074/isosettingsmanager)).

Now, after some time, I understood that I can merge first two stages: caching and writing to `IsoStorage`. Now I'm thinking of something like

```
    private int? deliveryId = null;
    public int DeliveryId
    {
        get { return deliveryId ?? IsoSettingsManager.GetProperty<int>("DeliveryId"); }
        set { deliveryId = value; IsoSettingsManager.SetProperty("DeliveryId", value); }
    }
```

Where setting property is

```
public static void SetProperty(string propertyName, object content)
    {
        if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
            return;

        if (content == null)
            RemoveProperty(propertyName); // if (isoSettings.Contains(propertyName)) isoSettings.Remove(propertyName);

        isoSettings[propertyName] = content;
        isoSettings.Save();
    }
```

What do you think about it?

First thing that comes to my mind is to make `SetProperty` to return the setted value so I'd be able to use it like

```
public int DeliveryId
{
    set { deliveryId = IsoSettingsManager.SetProperty("DeliveryId", value); }
    ***
```

unsetting `DeliveryId = null;` is not working for `int`s (fair enough), and I couldn't yet find how to push/pull them effectively.

Answer (score 2):

**Style**

It won't hurt you and makes your code less error prone, if you would use braces `{}` also for single `if` statements.

Commented code (`// if (isoSettings.Contains(propertyName)) isoSettings.Remove(propertyName);`) should be removed completely. You should instead use a code versioning system like svn or git.

**Update based on the comments below**
It is not about a comment but about commented out code which is just **dead code**. What value has dead code ? Does it make your live code more readable or does it make your live code easier to understand ? No, it is quite the opposite.

Asume the following

```
public static void SetProperty(string propertyName, object content)
{
    //if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
    //    return;

    //if (content == null)
        RemoveProperty(propertyName); // if (isoSettings.Contains(propertyName)) isoSettings.Remove(propertyName);

    isoSettings[propertyName] = content;
    isoSettings.Save();
}
```

this is quite hard to read and understatnd by **Mr.Maintainer**.

This instead

```
public static void SetProperty(string propertyName, object content)
{
    RemoveProperty(propertyName);

    isoSettings[propertyName] = content;
    isoSettings.Save();
}
```

is much better to understand.

If you check something into svn/git you always should add a descriptive message to the commit.

**`SetProperty()` method**

> ```
> if (content == null)
>         RemoveProperty(propertyName); // if (isoSettings.Contains(propertyName)) isoSettings.Remove(propertyName);
>
>     isoSettings[propertyName] = content;
>     isoSettings.Save();
> ```

this does not make sense to me. If `content==null` you first remove the property, and then you add it. Next time passing `null` you just do the same.

You should consider returning after you have removed the property. There is no need to save the setting.

**SetProperty() returning setted value**

This is in my opinion a bad idea for a method which seems to be like a property setter. A property setter should only **set** a properties value.

Comment: First of all, thanks for an answer. I thought it would stay unanswered for ages. Style - i think, the most important part of the style is : it should be the same everywhere. I prefer to skip {} for a single 'if' and i think its fine while i'm using it everywhere.

I also read some articles about using svn instead of comments, but i real life, i never user that. Its much faster to read a comment than to search svn for a old version of file. Can you please share more experience on this field, if it works fine for you?

And your notes about SetProperty() makes total sense, thanks.